# Transparency for my objects isn't working in Maya 2017

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm using Maya 2017. I can assign a colors to my objects. But the problem is that I can't do anything with transparency.

My object is a sphere and I color it in red. Then I go to transparency channel and choose a checker. I click on checker but nothing is changed in my object's transparency in Viewport. Even if I press `6` on a keyboard.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Quit Maya and open it again. In a new scene paste this MEL code in `Input Field` of a `Script Editor` and press `Execute` blue button. This makes new polySphere with Phong Shader assigned to it. Then just read in your premultiplied RGBA texture (in `png` format) with alpha channel like you see in a picture. Upload it via `Color`channel only (`Transparency` will be connected automatically).

[image]

```
polySphere -r 3 -sx 25 -sy 25 ;
shadingNode -asShader phong ;
sets -renderable true -noSurfaceShader true -empty -name phong1SG ;
connectAttr -f phong1.outColor phong1SG.surfaceShader ;
assignCreatedShader "phong" "" phong1 "pSphere1" ;
sets -e -forceElement phong1SG ;

defaultNavigation -createNew -destination "phong1.color" ;
createRenderNode -allWithTexturesUp "defaultNavigation -force true -connectToExisting -source %node -destination phong1.color" "" ;
defaultNavigation -defaultTraversal -destination "phong1.color" ;

shadingNode -asTexture -isColorManaged file ;
shadingNode -asUtility place2dTexture ;

connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.coverage file1.coverage ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.translateFrame file1.translateFrame ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.rotateFrame file1.rotateFrame ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.mirrorU file1.mirrorU ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.mirrorV file1.mirrorV ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.stagger file1.stagger ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.wrapU file1.wrapU ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.wrapV file1.wrapV ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.repeatUV file1.repeatUV ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.offset file1.offset ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.rotateUV file1.rotateUV ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.noiseUV file1.noiseUV ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.vertexUvOne file1.vertexUvOne ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.vertexUvTwo file1.vertexUvTwo ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.vertexUvThree file1.vertexUvThree ;
connectAttr -f place2dTexture1.vertexCameraOne file1.vertexCameraOne ;
connectAttr place2dTexture1.outUV file1.uv ;
connectAttr place2dTexture1.outUvFilterSize file1.uvFilterSize ;

defaultNavigation -force true -connectToExisting -source file1 -
destination phong1.color ;
window -e -vis false createRenderNodeWindow ;
connectAttr -force file1.outColor phong1.color ;
```

If it doesn't help try to enable `Legacy Default Viewport` option instead of `Viewport 2.0`.

Open your `Preferences...` and under the `Display` section change the Rendering Engine to `OpenGL - Legacy...` then restart Maya.